# Server 2008 R2 Logs off while trying to RDP into it

Tags: windows, active-directory, remote-desktop

Background: Recently, some domain admins are not able to successfully remote into a particular server on the domain. They are able to remote in fine on all other servers within the same domain fine apart from just one.

My case: User1, User2, User3 are all domain admins and are part of the same security groups that have permissions to RDP into the server in question. User1 can access the server fine, User2 and User3 have difficulties logging in. They can see the "Applying user settings..", "Preparing desktop..." message but straight after are logged off from the server. They can access all the other servers on the domain. Tested RDP with User1 on the same PC as the other 2 user and User1 is able to log into the server fine without issues. User2 and User3 were able to access the server fine till a few days back.

Has anyone else have faced a similar issue or have any ideas for me?

Thanks.

Comment: Managed to resolve this issue by deleting the user profiles of the problematic users from the server in question. They were able to lag back in fine.